# How to mount Windows 11 nvme in Linux

Tags: linux, windows-11, partition-recovery, nvme, fedora-38

I was given Dell Inspiron 7706 laptop with Windows 11 that got corrupted during upgrade (power loss).
It won't boot Windows anymore (\windows\system32\winload.efi missing or damaged).
I have successfully booted Fedora-38-Live off a USB drive to try and get the user data off.
I have been unsuccessful, trying to get the nvme mounted and am looking for your help.

I had hoped to find 2 NTFS partitions on the nvme, but no such luck. Instead I find these devices:

```
# ls -l /dev/nvme*
  crw-------. 1 root root 238, 0 Jan 29 18:54 /dev/nvme0
  brw-rw----. 1 root disk 259, 1 Jan 29 19:01 /dev/nvme0n1
  crw-------. 1 root root 238, 1 Jan 29 18:54 /dev/nvme1
  brw-rw----. 1 root disk 259, 0 Jan 30 12:48 /dev/nvme1n1
```

That I have further explored that with:

```
# fdisk -l
  Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
  Disk model: H10 HBRPEKNX0202A NVMe INTEL 512GB
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0x00000000
  Device         Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
  /dev/nvme1n1p1          1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT

  Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 27.25 GiB, 29260513280 bytes, 57149440 sectors
  Disk model: H10 HBRPEKNX0202AO NVMe INTEL 32GB
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

This being a standard, out of the box, Windos-11 system, my assumption is that /dev/nvme1n1 is the system disk (C:) and /dev/nvme0n1 is the recovery disk (D:). I have explored /dev/nvme1n1 with gparted (gpart scan), which finds no file systems:

```
# gparted /dev/nvme1n1
    Partition         File System      Size         Used     Unused    Flags
    /dev/nvme1n1       ataraid        476.94 GiB     --        --
# lsblk -f
  nvme1n1     isw_raid_member 1.4.01
  └─md126
  nvme0n1     isw_raid_member 1.4.01
  └─md127
```

Now I am fresh out of ideas and turn to you for help on how to get this storage mounted, so I can get the data off, so I can turn this into a sweet little Linux laptop next.

Comment: You can’t; Windows was installed on an Intel RST RAID. Linux does not support Intel RST. Either Intel RST or Optane (due to the 32GB drive) I am guessing you can’t confirm if it was Intel RST or Optane?

Comment: Neither nvme nor smartctl will tell me, but I believe Intel RST was phased out after the 7th generation Intel platform. This laptop has an 11th generation Intel Core i7-1165G7, so based on that, it should be Optane or something newer than that.

Comment: You have it backwards.  Intel Optane was phased out, specifically, newer hardware we never released. Intel RST is still supported. However, gparted is telling you, the nvme is part of a RAID. [Which again is due to the Intel Optane NVMe drive you have installed.](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Intel/HBRPEKNX0202A?qs=Cb2nCFKsA8oqgYB%2FJhn%2Fmw%3D%3D).  In either case Intel RST would have to be enabled to support such a configuration.

Comment: Thanks. You are right of course. The page you linked shows part# HBRPEKNX0202A is SSD Intel Optane. That part# agrees with what smartctl AND nvme AND fdisk AND parted were telling me. I guest, I will have to find someone who can boot Windows 11 off a USB, to retrieve those user data.